# Responsive text unstable resize

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am using viewport width (vw) on all elements widths to make them responsive.

But the actual resizing comes somewhat unstable.

[Here](http://otprazdnyi.ru/temp/reputation10/screen.jpg) is how it looks:

[image]

Top image is how it looks at 1366px viewport width and the bottom is at 766px.

The odd thing is that it returns to normal at 707px and breaks again at 700px and returns to normal at 691px and breaks again at 680px and so on (all numbers are approximate).

Please check the working model example [here](http://otprazdnyi.ru/temp/)

P.S. is it ok to use vw width exclusively?

Comment: Why not reduce the cart's width to 20vw?

Comment: i changed the cart's width to 20vw and the problem still persists. And also if I add some more free space the design doesn't break. But it obviously won't be the right solution.

Comment: Works perfectly in Firefox. Buggy as described in Chrome. Seeing as - when resized - free space on right "hops", I wonder if it wouldn't be an issue with rounding?

Comment: To the person asking for close: what's unclear?? OP wants it to stay on 1 line and learn why this behavior occurs.

Comment: If you want these 3 elements to stay on 1 row, you should use CSS display as table-cell (and table, with or w/o table-layout:fixed). That's resilient. A lot.

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with VW as a length of width, but I have had problems like this before and it usually had to do with layout. Try floating that last element right instead of left?

Answer (score 0):

There is a known bug for vw units when resizing browser in Chrome. The size is calculated wrong, but correct it self as soon as you update the browser.

I found a fix for this and I have also tried this succesfully my self.

```
causeRepaintsOn = jQuery("h1, h2, h3, p");
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    causeRepaintsOn.css("z-index", 1);
});
```

Read more here:
http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/